# Get element's horizontal and vertical position with javascript

Tags: javascript

I made a script that moves my "character" (element ID="character") to where I click. But I need to get it's position so I can make it "walk" to where I click instead of it just appearing there.

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showCoords(evt){
  document.getElementById("character").style.left = evt.pageX;
  document.getElementById("character").style.top = evt.pageY;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onmousedown="showCoords(event)">
<div id="character" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; width: 80px; height: 40px; background:black;"> Char </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically I just want to retrieve the element's horizontal and vertical position at the beginning of my function. So I can later use those variables. How do I do it?

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused:  does `document.getElementById("character").style.left` and `.top` not give you those values to start with?

Comment: It depends on the `position` property of that element. For example, if its value is `relative`, then the `left` and `top` properties (if ever defined) will tell you just how many pixels the element is relative to its parent.

Comment: I thought document.getElementById("character").style.left was only to change it's position. How can I print that value? That would answer my question. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only need this to work in reasonably modern browsers, then `document.getElementById("character").getBoundingClientRect()` will have `left` and `top` properties that give you the offsets from the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Using MooTools you can get the position of an element with:

```
$('element').getPosition(); // returns {x: 100, y: 500};
```

[MooTools docs: Element Method: getPosition](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Dimensions#Element%3agetPosition)

Comment: Not very relevant if the OP is not using MooTools.

Comment: But relevant enough if looking for a way to solve that problem with one of the very good frameworks available for Javascript ;)